# mysqli bind_result only working for columns of type INT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a mySQL table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coupons` (
    `coupon_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `coupon_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `coupon_expiration_date` date NOT NULL,
    `coupon_discount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `coupon_created_date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`coupon_id`)
)
```

And one entry in this table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `coupons` (`coupon_id`, `coupon_code`, `coupon_expiration_date`, `coupon_discount`, `coupon_created_date`) VALUES (1, 'test', '2012-11-30', '11.00', '2012-10-22');
```

When trying to query this table using the following PHP code:

```
$strSelectCoupons = "SELECT coupon_id FROM coupons";
if($stmtSelectCoupons = $mysqlConn->prepare($strSelectCoupons))
{
    $stmtSelectCoupons->execute();
    $stmtSelectCoupons->bind_result($iCouponId);

    while($stmtSelectCoupons->fetch())
    {
        echo $iCouponId;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Prepared statement error: " . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

As expected we see a '1' printed to the screen.

However, if we try to execute the following PHP code:

```
$strSelectCoupons = "SELECT coupon_id, coupon_code FROM coupons";
if($stmtSelectCoupons = $mysqlConn->prepare($strSelectCoupons))
{
    $stmtSelectCoupons->execute();
    $stmtSelectCoupons->bind_result($iCouponId, $strCouponCode);

    while($stmtSelectCoupons->fetch())
    {
        echo $iCouponId . "<br />";
        echo $strCouponCode . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Prepared statement error: " . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

No results are displayed, no errors are printed, no errors are logged and the rest of the page does not render.

In fact, the only time that this actually works as expected is when returning ONLY coupon_id. If we change the select statement to return only coupon_code for example, this again will cause the page to bomb out.

Any ideas as to what is causing this to fail?

Apache version: 2.2.2

PHP version: 5.3.14

mySQL version: 5.0.95-community

**EDIT:**

Under further investigation, bind_result is only working with columns of type INT, and fails when trying to bind any column of another type.

Comment: are you sure `coupon_code` is actually the name of a column in the table? maybe there's a typo somewhere?

Comment: Just wondering - When you execute the working query does the coupon_id auto_increment actually increment the value?

Comment: sgroves: `coupon_code` is the actual name of the column in the table. The problem happens with ALL columns except for `coupon_id`.

Comment: PhilNerd: auto_increment is a property of the column `coupon_id` such that when I insert a record into my table the `coupon_id` will increment by 1, this has nothing to do with selecting rows.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#101543) points to [a bug in the MySQL Client Library](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47928) that causes a crash with large data columns.

Reportedly, mysqlnd and MySQL's Connector/C do not exhibit this issue, or if possible you can call [`mysqli_stmt_store_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`.

Answer (score 0):

Very old topic, but I found a "solution", a weird one, put your bind_result in IF

```
if(!$stmtSelectCoupons->bind_result($iCouponId, $strCouponCode)) { // TODO error }
```